# Cplex objetive function in java(eclipse) implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, cplex

This is my objetive function in cplex:

minimize sum(j in horas, k in trabajos) ((1/prioridad[j][k]) * (sum(i in personas) x[i][j][k] - min_demanda[j][k]));

and this is how I tried to do it in java but it doesn't works well ( the objetive value is zero and all the var x[][][] too so its must be negative in that case because there is the term -min_demanda[j] (not null)):

```
                double valorFuncionObjetivo = 0;
                IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();

                IloNumVar[][][] x = new IloNumVar[Map.NumPersM][Map.NumHrsM][Map.NumTrab];

                for (int i = 0; i < Map.NumPersM; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Map.NumHrsM; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < Map.NumTrab; k++) {

                        x[i][j][k] = cplex.boolVar();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.Preprocessing.Presolve, false);

                // Model            
                IloLinearNumExpr funcion_objetivo = cplex.linearNumExpr();

                for (int j = 0; j < Map.NumHrsM; j++) {
                     for (int k = 0; k < Map.NumTrab; k++) {
                          for (int i = 0; i < Map.NumPersM; i++) {

                                funcion_objetivo.addTerm(x[i][j][k],Map.Demandas[j][k].Prioridad);
                          }
                       funcion_objetivo.setConstant(-(Map.Demandas[j][k].Prioridad)*Map.Demandas[j][k].Min_personas);  
                     }
                } 

                cplex.addMinimize( funcion_objetivo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the way you set the constant term in your objective. You code is

```
for (int j = 0; j < Map.NumHrsM; j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < Map.NumTrab; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Map.NumPersM; i++) {
      funcion_objetivo.addTerm(x[i][j][k],Map.Demandas[j][k].Prioridad);
    }
    funcion_objetivo.setConstant(-(Map.Demandas[j][k].Prioridad)*Map.Demandas[j][k].Min_personas);  
  }
}
```

So in each iteration of the j/k loop you *overwrite* the constant term. If the last term happens to be 0 then the constant term in the objective will be 0.
You probably want to sum the constant like this (I added `funcion_objectivo.getConstant()`):

```
for (int j = 0; j < Map.NumHrsM; j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < Map.NumTrab; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Map.NumPersM; i++) {
      funcion_objetivo.addTerm(x[i][j][k],Map.Demandas[j][k].Prioridad);
    }
    funcion_objetivo.setConstant(funcion_objectivo.getConstant() - (Map.Demandas[j][k].Prioridad)*Map.Demandas[j][k].Min_personas);  
  }
}
```

Also, you can `System.out.println(funcion_objective.getConstant())` to double check that the constant term is indeed non-zero.

I am not sure whether the fact that all variables are 0 is unexpected or not. If that is unexpected then you are probably missing some constraints that require the variables to be non-zero. A good way to debug this is to assign names to your variables and constraints (use the `setName()` function), export the model to LP file format using `cplex.exportModel("model.lp")` and then check the created `model.lp` file in a text editor to make sure all constraints look as expected.